# Incorrect Login, Message Dialogue looping

Tags: java, joptionpane

After clicking OK, the 1st loop must be initiated and then I'll try to input the log-in again. TIA Edit: Supposedly, when I put a wrong log-in details, the message dialogue will prompt, and after clicking the "OK" button of message dialogue, I should go back attempting a log-in again. But the error appears, after clicking the "OK" button of message dialogue, it just goes on and prompt me another message dialogue. I can't go back to attempting a log-in.
joptionpane problem

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Ok")){//Button for Action Listener
int attempt=0;
{
    while(attempt<5){//Max attempt is 5
        if ((txtF.getText().equals("user"))&&
        (passF.getText().equals("pass"))){ 
        ProjectJava_Main finalp2 = new ProjectJava_Main();
        finalp2.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
        }//Redirect to another class if true

        else{//Increment,invalid login
        attempt++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"INCORRECT LOGIN ");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Log-In attempt:" +""+attempt);      
        }

            if (attempt==5){//If max 5 attempt, should exit
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You reached the maximum
            attempt!");
            System.exit(0);
            }
        }//Error on this part can't debug
    }
}
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")){
    System.exit(0);
}//Exit part
```

Comment: What you mean incorrect login message? What is the expected behaviour and how does the application behave instead? Please update your problem description to include these details.

Comment: Supposedly, when I put a wrong log-in details, the message dialogue will prompt, and after clicking the "OK" button of message dialogue, I should go back attempting a log-in again. But the error appears, after clicking the "OK" button of message dialogue, it just goes on and prompt me another message dialogue. I can't go back to attempting a log-in.